# Decoding html entities but keeping ampersand entity encoded in ASP.NET MVC5 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-encode, ampersand

When rendering html in a View, I'd like to actually display html entities that are encoded in text I'm displaying. I can accomplish this with `@Html.Raw()`. When it comes to ampersand entity though, with `@Html.Raw()` it is rendered as `&` and not `&amp;`, which is not valid html. Is it possible to get an output with decoded html entities but ampersand entity encoded so the rendered html is valid? Or do I have to do some preprocessing before rendering the text with `@html.Raw()`?

Example:

```
string text = "&lt;h3&gt;Mike &amp; Jane&lt;/h3&gt;";
```

I'd like the output of `@html.Raw(text)` (or other function) to be:

```
<h3>Mike &amp; Jane</h3>
```

Thanks

Comment: The quick fix would be to double-encode the ampersand, for example using a string replace `&amp;amp;`.

Comment: That will do. Thank you